# Заменить символ которого нет в строке

Tags: python

Здравутвуйте!
Нужно заменить символы которых нет в строке `basestr` на `-`

```
def replacesym(a, b):
    #код "заменятеля"

basestr = "ac"
something = "abcd"
replacesym(basestr, something)
#something = "a-c-"
```

Сам пишу простенький клиент ютуба на mpv и fzf но fzf выдает ошибку при не стандартных символах в строке (допустим | или ►)
вот кусок моего кода:

```
notinstr = []
   for i in allname:
       for j in basestr:
           isfound = i.find(j)
           if isfound == -1:
               notinstr.append(j)
print(notinstr)
```

но он выдает все что угодно, но не спец символы
Вот код полностью: https://pastebin.com/dVRWUU1p

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку решить задачу и что не получилось. Задача выглядит учебной. Без кода её закроют.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from string import ascii_letters as letters, digits

def replacesym(a):
    for char in a:
        if char not in letters and char not in digits:
            a = a.replace(char, '-')
    return a

something = "a►b#c|d>"
print(replacesym(something))
#a-b-c-d-
```

Если символ не буква и не цифра, то он будет заменён на "-"

---

Если нужен именно свой фильтр:

```
def replacesym(basestr,a):
    for char in a:
        if char not in basestr:
            a = a.replace(char, '-')
    return a

basestr = 'abcd'
something = "a►b#c|d>"
print(replacesym(basestr,something))
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

такая функция уже есть в библиотеке re:

```
from re import sub

basestr = "ac"
something = "abcd"

print(sub(fr'[^{basestr}]', '-', something))  # a-c-
```